# stop jenkins from checking for internet connectivity by trying to reach google

Tags: jenkins

I want to set up Jenkins. When I go to install or update plugins, Jenkins automatically checks for "Internet connectivity". For reasons unclear to me, it appears that the Jenkins definition of "Internet connectivity" is "able to reach google.com". I am located in China, and trying to contact google over an unprotected connection is guaranteed to fail.

I'd like to skip (or at least redirect) this check, which takes a long time, can never succeed, isn't relevant to the task that triggers it, and isn't even used by Jenkins (the actual plugin download goes through fine after Jenkins gives up on reaching google). Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

open /var/lib/jenkins/updates/default.json file, you will see the connectionCheckUrl is set to www.google.com. change it to www.baidu.com, and restart.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to proxy, you can always modify the `hosts` file on the Jenkins machine (location depends on the OS), and redirect google.com to whatever IP you want.